# How to multiple insert data to MySQL having auto incremented now() function?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Here how my tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id VARCHAR(5),
  time_value DATETIME
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO my_table(user_id,time_value)
VALUES
  (100, NOW()),
  (200, NOW()),
  (300, NOW()),
  (400, NOW()),
  (500, NOW());
```

**My Output:**

```
id  user_id time_value  
1   100     2014-09-06 23:58:58      
2   200     2014-09-06 23:58:58    
3   300     2014-09-06 23:58:58      
4   400     2014-09-06 23:58:58      
5   500     2014-09-06 23:58:58
```

I ought this answer

**Require Output:**

```
id  user_id time_value  
1   100     2014-09-06 23:58:58      
2   200     2014-09-06 23:59:58    
3   300     2014-09-07 00:00:58      
4   400     2014-09-07 00:01:58      
5   500     2014-09-07 00:02:58
```

Can have possible in MySQL DATETIME function ? if possible means,
time_value based insert the row value in this table ?

Comment: `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` and another minute to each row

Comment: not working....current time came. @prix... interval 1 minute not working boss.

Comment: [Works fine for me, see here...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b5f6e/1/0)

Comment: i ought dynamically...it will generate automatically. mysql datetime functionality based.

Comment: i am using php/mysql...so i need front end insert the query...@prix

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the `NOW()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) says, in part,

> `NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger,
>   `NOW()` returns the time at which the function or triggering statement
>   began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for `SYSDATE()`, which
>   returns the exact time at which it executes.

This means that if call use the `NOW()` function multiple times in a single query, they all return precisely the same value.  If you want to insert several *different* timestamps with a single query, you're going to have to specify those differences explicitly. @Prix offered you a good way to do that.